# Is "ocho días" neutral Spanish?

Tags: definiciones, diferencias-regionales, méxico, tiempo

In Mexican Spanish,

- "Ocho días" = One week
- "Quince días" = Two weeks
- "Una quincena" = Two weeks (one fortnight)
- "Quincenal" = Every two weeks

Is this usage unique to Mexico?

(Some of the comments at [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13014/9385) made me wonder about this.)

Comment: En España no se usa.

Comment: En Cuba se usa ‘quince días’

Answer (score 8):

It appears *ocho días* = one week is common in some regions. I've never heard it in Argentina, nor the expressions mentioned in the other question (such as *de aquí en ocho*). It's either *siete días* or *una semana*.

The equivalence of 15 days to two weeks, on the other hand, is common here, and I gather it's common elsewhere. *Quincena* is mostly used in reference to wages (for someone who gets paid every two weeks); metonymically, it refers both to the span of time and to the money itself.

If you go to a doctor and s/he wants a follow-up in two weeks, s/he will say either *«Te veo en dos semanas»* or *«Te veo en quince días»*. This is so common that I guess nobody would mistake *quince días* for fifteen actual days unless in very specific contexts.

*Quincenal* is also usually "once a fortnight", but it may imply "twice a month".

Answer (score 3):

Also commonly used in the Quito region of Ecuador; not sure if it's common on the coast.

Comment: Thank you, and welcome. // What about the other expressions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't aknowledge that "ocho días" means "one week" in Spain. It seems to me that that exact wording is local Mexican usage.

Answer (score 1):

As Mexican I can answer the same way the given answer in the post

A week is not made from 8 days, but when something is bound to happen into a week from the current day, we will say "8 days from/starting today"

Some explanation

- 1 day is today (Monday)
- 2 days will be tomorrow Tuesday
- 3 days will be Wednesday
- 4 days will be Thursday
- 5 days will be Friday
- 6 days will be Saturday
- 7 days will be Sunday
- 8 days will be Monday(again)

This means that "de hoy en 8" : "8 days from today" means that something is happening one week ahead.

Basically you count the days and add 1 (to include the current day in the counting)

Comment: Mike, now that you've gotten the hang of checking your spelling, how about fixing this post up?  With special focus on "weak"?  In terms of content, I do like this post.  I'd like to be able to change my vote.